# Rhino: How to pass Java object to script, where can be referenced as "this"

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

I am new to JSR-223 Java Scripting, actually I'm switching from [**MVEL**](http://mvel.codehaus.org/) to standard [**Mozilla Rhino JS**](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/). I have read all documentation, but get stuck. I have tried to reference some Java objects from script by bindings just like in tutorial:

```
    // my object
    public class MyBean {
       public String getStringValue() { return "abc" };
    }

    // initialization
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

    // add bindings
    engine.put("bean", new MyBean());

    // evaluate script, output is "abc"
    engine.eval("print(bean.stringValue)");
```

Java object is referenced from script as property `bean`. So far so good.

But I want to reference my object in script as `this`, I want to use its properties and methods without any prefix or explicitely with prefix `this`. Just like this:

```
    // add bindings
    engine.put(....., new MyBean()); // or whatever ???

    // evaluate scripts, all have the same output "abc"
    engine.eval("print(stringValue)");
    engine.eval("print(this.stringValue)");
```

I know that `this` in JavaScript has special meaning (as in Java) but in MVEL scripting that could be done by using custom [`ParserContext`](http://codehaus.org/~mvel/javadoc/2.0/org/mvel2/ParserContext.html) and custom [`PropertyHandler`](http://codehaus.org/~mvel/javadoc/2.0/org/mvel2/integration/PropertyHandler.html).

**Is something like this possible in Rhino?**

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in JavaScript it really only makes sense to think about `this` being set in the context of a function being invoked. Thus I think you should be able to use the "invoke" method on the ScriptEngine (which has to be cast to "Invocable"):

```
  ((Invocable) engine).invokeMethod(objectForThis, "yourFunction", arg, arg ...);
```

Now the "objectForThis" reference is (in my experience) generally something that was returned from a prior call to "eval()" (or "invokeMethod" I guess); in other words, it's supposed to be an object in the appropriate language for the script engine. Whether you could pass in a Java object there (and have it work out), I don't know for sure.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I need! Actually, I have to wrap user script with `"function run() { %s }"` and then call `run` by invokeMethod() as you suggested and `this` works for me. One inconvenience is that  user script has to use `return` keyword strictly -- with eval() script returns result also without `return` keyword -- but never mind, it's much better than another solution.

Comment: Oops, not exactly. Sadly it works for expressions only with `this` prefix. I.e. `print("this.stringValue")` works but `print("stringValue")` doesn't.

Comment: ?? Huh?  I don't understand what that means. It's just like using the ".call()" method in Javascript - it invokes the function with `this` bound to an object.  If "stringValue" is a property name on the `this` object, then that's just how JavaScript works always, Rhino or not.

Comment: Please look at test case in separate answer [bellow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709542/rhino-how-to-pass-java-object-to-script-where-can-be-referenced-as-this/6764848#6764848) -- length of comment exceeded, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

I try to implement [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709542/rhino-how-to-pass-java-object-to-script-where-can-be-referenced-as-this/6709811#6709811) from answer from Pointy (thanks again), but this workaround doesn't work for properties without `this` prefix, which seems to be IMHO the very same. Instead of using Rhino 1.5 from Java API, there is original Rhino 1.7 from Mozilla. Test case is here:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Context;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Function;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable;
import org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Wrapper;

public class RhinoTest2 {

  private Obj obj = new Obj();

  public class Obj {
    public String getStringValue() {
      return "abc";
    }
  }

  private Object eval(String expression) {
    Context cx = Context.enter();
    try {
      ScriptableObject scope = cx.initStandardObjects();

      // convert my "this" instance to JavaScript object  
      Object jsObj = Context.javaToJS(obj, scope);

      // prepare envelope function run()    
      cx.evaluateString(scope, 
        String.format("function run() { %s }", expression), 
        "<func>", 1, null);

      // call method run()
      Object fObj = scope.get("run", scope);
      Function f = (Function) fObj;
      Object result = f.call(cx, scope, (Scriptable) jsObj, null);
      if (result instanceof Wrapper)
        return ((Wrapper) result).unwrap();
      return result;

    } finally {
      Context.exit();
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {

    // works
    eval("return this.getStringValue()");
    eval("return this.stringValue");

    // doesn't work, throws EcmaError: ReferenceError: "getStringValue" is not defined.
    eval("return getStringValue()");
    eval("return stringValue");
  }
}
```

Why `this.getStringValue()/this.stringValue` works and `getStringValue()/stringValue` doesn't? Have some point overlooked? Pointy?

Comment: Because that's simply not how JavaScript works.  There is **never** a situation where the value of `this` is assumed as a reference base. JavaScript is different from Java in this regard (as in many others). If you want a property of `this`, you **must** reference it explicitly (or reference a copy of the value, or something like that).

Comment: OK, thanks again. However is MVEL unstable and relatively low supported, it is much easier to integrate with Java application than Rhino. JavaScript is simply a different animal...